# Can oxygen 'leach' along a wire?

Tags: physical-chemistry, diffusion

[If this is not the right SE for this question, apologies.]

Automobile gasoline engine controls use oxygen sensors in the exhaust stream.  The [Wikipedia article on Oxygen Sensors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxygen_sensor) notes that (some) such sensors require a reference sample - that the sensor actually measures the difference between the concentration in the exhaust and that in ambient air.

What I read (references below) seems to say that this reference oxygen is supplied by diffusion  ("leaching") along the length of the wires attached to said sensor.  I would appreciate hearing from someone who knows about such things, that this is plausible, and I'm not just misunderstanding what I read.  Thank you.

The linked Wikipedia article notes

> In theory, the sensor wire harness and connector are sealed. Air that
> leaches through the wire harness to the sensor is assumed to come from
> an open point in the harness – usually the ECU [Engine Control Unit],
> which is housed in an enclosed space like the trunk or vehicle
> interior.

Also, manufacturer's service guidance for such an engine (paywalled) supports this idea

> ... This external clean air reference is obtained by way of the oxygen
> sensor signal and heater wires. Any attempt to repair the wires,
> connectors, or terminals could result in the obstruction of the air
> reference and degraded sensor performance.
>
> ... Ensure the sensor or vehicle lead wires are not bent sharply or
> kinked. Sharp bends or kinks could block the reference air path
> through the lead wire.

Comment: I'd recommend https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/.  Oxygen permeability would depend on the material.

Comment: Alternatively, our [engineering.se] membership may be able to offer some insight.

Comment: Welcome George to Physics SE.  You already asked half a day earlier essentially the [same question on mechanics SE](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/92421). It is best to wait for answers on one SE site before posting it on another.  Whether oxygen actually "leaches" through metal or plastic might be a Physics SE question, but I believe your question is simply the source of the reference air in such sensors.

Comment: @DavidBailey I am fairly familiar with Mechanics SE.  From my experience there, that question is answered as much as it's likely to be.  My question here is perhaps ineptly put, but I thought I might get some explanation of how the purported mechanism might work.  I will go away now.